# Downgrade xlWings PRO

Tags: python-3.x, conda, xlwings

My trial licence for xlwings PRO expired and now I get a license validation error.I tried reinstalling xlwings to no avail: it still installed PRO version and is asking for valid license. Conda installation here, Python 3.7.

Any ideas?

I cannot find any info in documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to upgrade to the latest version - there was a bug with 0.19.0. A simple `conda upgrade xlwings` will fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I got it work with the awesomely quick help from xlwings themselves!

When I was trying PRO version I added python code to excel sheets with .py ending and that was triggering to use .pro version of xlwings and therefore asking for license. I just needed to delete those sheets with python code.

Maybe this will be useful for someone else...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
conda uninstall xlwings
pip uninstall xlwings
conda update --all
conda clean --all
conda install xlwings
```